# Visual studio like panels

Tags: .net, winforms, interface

I need to make some vertical docking/collapsible panels in the style of the Visual Studio IDE (like Solution explorer, Toolbox, Properties, etc...), does anyone know some examples or code for doing that?

Thanks,
R.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the DockPanel Suite from [here](http://dockpanelsuite.sourceforge.net/). Then your forms just have to inherit from DockContent and they can dock to a DockPanel similar to Visual Studio.

Comment: For a wpf solution see AvalonDock http://www.codeplex.com/AvalonDock this is replacing DockPanel Suite in SharpDevelop 4.0

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to do autohide? You probably need to look at userdraw controls. You'll need to implement the paint method and do all the work of shifting content around.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the ToolStripContainer

http://en.csharp-online.net/Tool,_Menu,_and_Status_Strips%E2%80%94The_ToolStripContainer

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229623.aspx

google the word "ToolStripContainer" and you'll come up with all sorts of samples.